# Reload data from url with timer

Tags: android, json, timer, refresh

I want to load data after every 2 min. How do I do it? I have implemented this.But its not working.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getData();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Loading new data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 10);
public void getData(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SP, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String ip_addr = preferences.getString("ip_addr",null);
        final String port = preferences.getString("port_no",null);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        String url = "http://"+ip_addr+":"+port+"/new_crushing_api.php";
//code
```

Comment: Why _10_? If you want to update your data every 2 min then it should be _120000_ in handler. Also `new Handler().postDelayed()...` means it will executed after 2 min and then stopped. So you can use _Timer_ or _CountDownTimer_ to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {
      getData();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Loading new 
 data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: The app is crashing after 1200000 time